# Import Excel Sheet data and show it in SAPUI5 Views

Tags: javascript, sapui5

How to import excel sheet data and show it in view using SAPUI5 Framework.I have an Excel sheet I wanted to upload it onclick of button and show all excel data in the form.

Comment: what did you try up to now? noone will hep you unless you tried yourself fist...

Comment: I tried with xlsx.js javascript library and now its working fine for me.
thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I used an ***xlsx.js*** javascript library to upload excel files in UI5. Its working fine for me and I can upload more than 1000 records at a time and able to show it in SAPUI5 view.

Below is a link to download xlsx.js library
https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx

Thanks